# Crystal Reports: Record Selection Snafu

Tags: sql, parameters, crystal-reports, record

I had received some really good help earlier, and I appreciate it. 
I have another record selection snafu.

1. I have a parameter that I need to set as the end date.
2. I need to pull the most recent state before the end date from a table titled state_change.
3. I need to exclude any records from the report who are not in the required states at that period in time.

state is set currently to be state_change.new_state

```
( {@grouping} = "Orders" and rec_date < {?endDate} and {@state} in [0,2,5] )

OR

( {@grouping} = "Stock" and rec_date < {?endDate} and {@state} in [1,2,3,5,7] )
```

If I could run a SQL query to pull this information, it would probably work, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Essentially, I need @state to be:

```
Select max(new_state)  
From state_change
where change_time < {?endDate}
```

but on a per item level.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to use a command object with a parameter for your end date, or create a parameterized stored procedure.  The command object will allow you to enter all the sql you need, like joining your results with the max newState value before the end date:

```
select itemID, new_state, rec_date, max_newState from
(select itemID, new_state, rec_date from table) t inner join
(Select itemID, max(new_state) as max_newState
    From state_change
    where change_time < {?endDate}  
    group by itemID) mx on t.itemid = mx.itemID and t.new_state = mx.max_newState
```

I can't tell if your orders and stock groupings are in the same table, so I'm not sure how you need to limit your sets by the correct state values.

Comment: They are actually in two different tables, but I am sure I can probably just union all and separate the two.